# Current source and electromagnetic interferance

Tags: capacitor, electromagnetism, current-source, emc, counter

I have a current source which has to be really precise in order to charge a capacitor and count a certain time (about 100 ms.)

If anybody has seen a component which allows to count a time (without a microcontroller) when an event occurs and able to set an output after a certain delay programmed by a resistor/capacitor, it will be a pleasure to know it.

For counting this large time (about 100 ms,) I can't use a big capacitor as the tolerance diminishes with the size of the capacitor and so I have to have a low current source. The current is around 100 µA.

That seems very low to me and I do not know if it is reliable to use this kind of current source.

I imagine that if I have 10A next to this current source, it will be possible to have a magnetic coupling between the two currents, and I think that it is possible to have a lot of other possible coupling that I do not know.

So do you think that it could be reliable if I do a correct layout by minimizing the length of the trace of the current source. Here is my circuit:

[image]

Comment: You ask about a circuit that you already made yet you are also asking for suggestions to do this in a different way as you appear uncertain that what you're doing is a good solution. My advice: focus on what you want to achieve (explain that) and I do not mean getting a small current (that's about this circuit's implementation) but what do you want to do with this circuit?

Comment: I think your project requirement can be summarized to: (1) Use a 100uA constant current source to  charge a capacitor, (2) Use a precise 100ms timer/stop watch to time when the capacitor is charged to a particular level. Requirement (2) hardware is easy to find. For Requirement (1), I would suggest the use the following: ***LM334  Adjustable Current Sources (Programmable From 1μA to 10mA)*** - TI
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm134.pdf?ts=1614553288549&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F. I have been playing with LM334 and found it flexible and newbie friendly.Cheers.

Comment: @tlfong01:  You've got it backwards.  Charge capacitor with a constant current source. Measure voltage.  When the voltage reaches a specific level, 100 milliseconds will have passed

Comment: Thank you for your comment. And what about electromagnetic interferences on low current ?

Comment: Depends on the level, distance, frequency etc of the interference. In short, yes, if you have wiring close by with AC currents, they will induce.
Have you considered the effects of varying voltage , temperature etc on your components affecting the timing?
If you want a simple and very accurate timing circuit, look at using a crystal and something like a CD4060 ic. 100ppm shouldn't be too hard to achieve and EMC might upset the timer, but is unlikely to cause it to drift.

Comment: What maximum size capacitor can you go to @jess? What minimum charge current would suit this capacitor without giving too big a timing error? Voltage induced (from a threat) in series with a current source is of no consequence.

Comment: @JRE, perhaps you are right. Actually I don't quite understand why any timing, 500ms, or otherwise, is required. I tend to think that perhaps timing is needed only during calibration phase. Afterwards perhaps only an accurate opAmp comparator, with Schmitt trigger hysteresis effect to offset noise, is all that necessary. Anyway, It would be nice if the OP can show us the big picture.

Comment: @tlfong01:  The timing is the whole point of the circuit.  The idea is to start charging then trigger some other action when the capacitor voltage reaches a specific level.  With a fixed charge current, a fixed voltage level, and a good capacitor it will always take the same time to go from the start of the charge cycle to triggering the next action.  It is essentially a [555 timer in monostable operation.](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555_timer.html)

Comment: @JRE, Ha, I earlier hesitated to comment because I worried that my broken English would make things more confusing. I know the objective is a precise timer in the range of 100mS and tolerance perhaps 1%/1ms. I did once thought the OP should have already considered inaccurate timers such as 555 monstable, but found it too inaccurate. If a accurate timer is all that required, then I would suggest a US$1 24MHz crystal oscillator module, and use a binary counter to count as accurate as required, perhaps up to 0.001ms accurate. So I think it is a waste of time without seeing the OP, big picture.

Comment: Have you looked into the linear/analog devices timerblox series? they make parts for most of the discrete uses of the 555

Comment: I will take a look on something similar of the 555 timer :)

Comment: @Jess Look into the [Wyatt peaking current source](https://www.edn.com/peaking-current-source-has-high-rejection/). (Also hee [here](https://www.multisim.com/content/hyMWisnQUQShzy5RU2bN5F/wyatt-cascaded-peaking-current-sink-and-source/).) It's designed to include the tempco of copper traces as well as the tempco of the devices included in the circuit. It's output is on the order of \$14.5\:\mu\text{A}\$. Which is a bit lower than you want. But it can be adapted. Wyatt worked at Honeywell Space Systems, Inc. at the time of this development. It's not well-known. But it may be helpful.

Comment: Thank your for all your comment ! I think I am on the right way :) Clearly you help me a lot !